# laser_geometry ros2 example

Tags: ros, transform, laser-geometry, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to get the at the end of the [laser_pipeline tutorial page](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_pipeline/Tutorials/IntroductionToWorkingWithLaserScannerData) to work in ROS2 Foxy. I've been complementing the code with the [tf2 message filter tutorial page](http://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Tf2/Using-Stamped-Datatypes-With-Tf2-Ros-MessageFilter.html) as well. My code right now looks like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

#include "tf2/exceptions.h"
#include "tf2_ros/transform_listener.h"
#include "tf2_ros/buffer.h"
#include "tf2_ros/create_timer_ros.h"
#include "tf2_ros/message_filter.h"

#ifdef TF2_CPP_HEADERS
#include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp"
#else
#include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h"
#endif

#include "geometry_msgs/msg/transform_stamped.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/laser_scan.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp"

#include "laser_geometry/laser_geometry.hpp"
#include "message_filters/subscriber.h"


using std::placeholders::_1;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;


class LaserTransformerPublisher : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    LaserTransformerPublisher()
    : Node("laser_tf_pub") {
        typedef std::chrono::duration<int> seconds_type;
        seconds_type buffer_timeout(1);
        // Publisher for pointcloud messages
        pointcloud_publisher_ = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>("laser_proj", 10);
        // TF2 message buffer
        tf_buffer_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::Buffer>(this->get_clock());
        auto timer_interface = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::CreateTimerROS>(
            this->get_node_base_interface(),
            this->get_node_timers_interface()
        );
        tf_buffer_->setCreateTimerInterface(timer_interface);
        transform_listener_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformListener>(*tf_buffer_);
        laser_sub_.subscribe(this, "/laser/full");
        tf_filter_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>>(
            laser_sub_, *tf_buffer_, target_frame_, 100, this->get_node_logging_interface(),
            this->get_node_clock_interface(), buffer_timeout
        );
        tf_filter_->registerCallback(&LaserTransformerPublisher::on_laser_scan_callback, this);
    }

  private:
    std::string target_frame_;
    std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::TransformListener> transform_listener_{nullptr};
    std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::Buffer> tf_buffer_;
    rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr pointcloud_publisher_{nullptr};
    message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan> laser_sub_;
    std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>> tf_filter_;
    laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;

    void on_laser_scan_callback(const sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr scan_in) {
        sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 cloud;
        try {
            projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("/robot", *scan_in, cloud, transform_listener_);
        } catch (tf2::TransformException & ex) {
            RCLCPP_WARN(this->get_logger(), "Failure %s\n", ex.what());
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<LaserTransformerPublisher>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following build error:

```
/home/vizca-nuc/dev_ws/src/vizca/vizca_laser_projector/src/laser_proj.cpp: In member function ‘void LaserTransformerPublisher::on_laser_scan_callback(sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >::SharedPtr)’:
/home/vizca-nuc/dev_ws/src/vizca/vizca_laser_projector/src/laser_proj.cpp:87:82: error: cannot convert ‘std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::TransformListener>’ to ‘tf2::BufferCore&’
   87 |             projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("/robot", *scan_in, cloud, transform_listener_);
      |                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                  |
      |                                                                                  std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::TransformListener>
In file included from /home/vizca-nuc/dev_ws/src/vizca/vizca_laser_projector/src/laser_proj.cpp:24:
/opt/ros/foxy/include/laser_geometry/laser_geometry.hpp:158:23: note:   initializing argument 4 of ‘void laser_geometry::LaserProjection::transformLaserScanToPointCloud(const string&, const LaserScan&, sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2&, tf2::BufferCore&, double, int)’
  158 |     tf2::BufferCore & tf,
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_proj.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/laser_proj.dir/src/laser_proj.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:78: CMakeFiles/laser_proj.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< vizca_laser_projector [3.87s, exited with code 2]
```

I'm not really sure why passing `transformer_listener_`, a `tf2_ros::TransformListener`, to `transformLaserScanToPointCloud` fails, given that the function expects a `tf2::BufferCore&` variable, which is a parent class that `tf2_ros::TransformListener` inherits from. Should I be casting `transformer_listener_` to something else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392935/laser_geometry-ros2-example/) by [lalvarez](https://answers.ros.org/users/85425/lalvarez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`TransformListener` does not inherit from `BufferCore`, you should pass the function the actual `tf_buffer_` object. The listener populates the buffer via a topic but they are not related in an inheritance tree.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, I added `*tf_buffer_` as an argument, added the libraries to package.xml and CMakeLists.txt and everything compiled and linked without problems.

---

Originally posted by [lalvarez](https://answers.ros.org/users/85425/lalvarez/) with karma: 13 on 2021-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1